# MySQL recursive categroies table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 top level categories (makeup,pharmacy,someother), each top level category have **SAME** sub-categories and child categories. For example

```
Makeup->Products->Face->Eye..
Pharmacy->Products->Face->Eye..
Someother->Products->Face->Eye..
```

I need to create table schema for it and I am not getting how I can make it happen. I will have links on page like when click on "Face" it will also retrive products from other top-level categories.

I have this schema

```
CREATE TABLE category(
        category_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        parent_id INT DEFAULT NULL
);
```

and categories

```
id | name        | parent_id
1 | Makeup   | 0
2 | Pharmacy   | 0
3 | Someother   | 0
4 | Products   | 1
5 | Products   | 2
6 | Products   | 3
```

if I insert above data I have 3 "Products" with differnt parents, I want to have only 1 "Products".

Should I create another table to store second-level category and another table to store third-label category? confused

[image]

```
TopLevel=Makeup
 ->Products 
  --Face 
    --Eye
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
    --Lips
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
  --Hand
    --Nails
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
    --Finger
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
  --Head
    --Hair
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
    --Ear
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
 ->Services
  --Face 
    --Eye
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
    --Lips
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
  --Hand
    --Nails
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
    --Finger
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
  --Head
    --Hair
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
    --Ear
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
      --Sub-category
        --Product1
        --Product2
        --...
TopLevel=Pharmacy
 ....
TopLevel=SomeOther
....
```

Comment: I think you might want to look into "pivot tables"

Comment: Creating multiple tables for categories is not good idea. One thing - just following the current schema which u did is good Or else remove parent_id from categories table & In your products table add fields as Cat_level_1, Cat_level_2 & fetch accordingly

Comment: A [Nested set model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) might be a [good alternative](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)